# C# trying to open remote file location but windows not passing credentials

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio-2010

So, basically what I'm doing is trying to open up \\whatever\c$ on a remote workstation. I'll start by saying that the application is executed using `<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />`
now when someone executes the application they actually use a different domain and username/password than what is used to sign onto the workstation. from within the application I can do whatever I want. but right now what I'm trying to accomplish is have a button link to \whatever\c$ and just open that up in explorer so I can look at some files, however I don't want to type in a password each time. especially considering it's the same credentials I used to open the app. any help would be appreciated. here's the current code I'm using.

```
            string startlocation = @"\\" + textBox1.Text + @"\C$";
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo pcsi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
            pcsi.FileName = "explorer.exe";
            pcsi.Arguments = startlocation;
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pcsi);
```

from what I can tell this should automatically pass the credentials used when the application was opened. but it still opens up the UAC asking for credentials. I'm stuck.

p.s. when I was looking for a similar situation on SO I noticed a lot of other people were asking how to open it with other credentials or impersonate that's not what I want to do. I want to use the credentials used for opening the app.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the main culprit for windows not passing credentials is Server Principle Names (SPNs), if you're not aware of them definitely do some reading.

Comment: I read up on [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc961723.aspx) but I don't see how that applies here. I'm not dealing with services.

Comment: It was just an idea, not sure if it applies to your scenario. There is something called the double-hop issue where credentials are unable to pass between servers, this is corrected by SPNs. See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverfaq/archive/2009/12/15/why-do-we-need-spn-for-file-server-nas-ras-file-share-system-dns-alias-cname.aspx)

Comment: I don't have any local folders that require admin in order to open so I cant really test local. but what I can do is use something like `system.io.directory` and do whatever I want or `system.io.file` and list everything. I just cant seem to get explorer to open and show me the contents without entering the credentials.

Comment: I've got to head off now, here are a few ideas. When you start the process, do you get a new line under task manager for explorer and is there a username beside it? Maybe there is something in the microsoft reference [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo(v=vs.110).aspx), getting your app working with the Username, password and domain hard-coded into the ProcessStartInfo object would be a start.